# Why aren't my QBoxLayouts working?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout

So, I took it down a few notches and am trying simple programs to get the hang of Qt's tools.

First I tried a simple label inside main() function, then a button inside it. All good.

Next, I tried the same, but inside a main window (using the Qt's created documents). After the one-button program worked, I did a two-button program, that simple. Worked.

Then, I tried Qt's Box Layouts.
In none of these "main window" tries, I changed the main.cpp file created by Qt.

Here's the mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QPushButton *button1;
    QPushButton *button2;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Next, the mainwindow.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle(tr("Two Button Example"));
    resize(400,300);

    button1 = new QPushButton(tr("Bye!"));
    button1->setGeometry(0,0,200,30);
    //button1->setParent(this);
    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
    button1->show();

    button2 = new QPushButton(tr("Hide B1!"));
    button2->setGeometry(0,0,200,30);
    //button2->setParent(this);
    connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),button2,SLOT(hide()));
    button2->show();

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    setLayout(layout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

I'm studying this book (for the layouts specifically, Chapter 2, the Find Dialog example (page 16 of the book, or 34 from the pdf file): [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 1st ed.pdf](http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/cs221/qt/books/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.pdf)

For this specific problem, I also used this: [QHBoxLayout - Qt Examples and Tutorials](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html)
What I noticed:

- Commenting the QHBoxLayout part, all the way to the "setLayout" function, makes no difference in the program. No test I've done is affected by this QBoxLayout thing;
- The "setGeometry" function sets the position (first two parameters) and size (width and heightm, last two parameters) of a widget. This position is related to the parent widget, which may be the screen itself when no parent is assigned;
- When the "setParent" functions for the buttons are commented and the "show" function is uncommented, the buttons are shown each in a separate window from the MainWindow. When I uncomment the "setParent" functions, the buttons are shown inside the MainWindow, and there's no difference if there are or no "show" functions for the buttons. The detail is, for the book I referenced, no example so far have had the need to declare the parent widgets, nor did the example in Qt's Examples and Tutorials site;
- If I don't use the "setGeometry" function, the buttons are big, like 600x600, whatever. They follow the rules above regarding the other functions, but they are huge and always one on top of the other, not side by side. The function "sizeHint()" used extensively in the book, also has no effect;

Appearently, it's all following the same syntaxes and rules of the examples. So, what am I doing wrong, or not doing here? If it's not a problem to enlight me with the "sizeHint()" function, too, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't call [`setLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout) on a [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) -- it already has its own custom layout that's responsible for a large part of its functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even remember the origin of the problem, but I have never been able to work with the layouts right in the window. In company I worked with Qt we used a central widget for managing layouts, so the diagram is: window -> central widget -> layouts -> subwidgets. If I modified your code so, it would look like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle(tr("Two Button Example"));
    resize(400,300);

    auto *parentWidget = new QWidget;
    auto button1 = new QPushButton(tr("Bye!"), parentWidget);
    button1->setGeometry(0,0,200,30);
    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));

    auto button2 = new QPushButton(tr("Hide B1!"), parentWidget);
    button2->setGeometry(0,0,200,30);
    connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),button2,SLOT(hide()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    parentWidget->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(parentWidget);
}
```

Also, I don't quite understand why do you try to set the button size if the layout resets it later. To change the size inside a layout you must change the `sizeHint` of a widget:

```
 setWindowTitle(tr("Two Button Example"));
 resize(400,300);

 auto *parentWidget = new QWidget;
 auto button1 = new QPushButton(tr("Bye!"), parentWidget);
 button1->setMaximumSize(20, 20);
 connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));

 auto button2 = new QPushButton(tr("Hide B1!"), parentWidget);
 button2->setMaximumSize(20, 20);
 connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),button2,SLOT(hide()));

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button1);
 layout->addWidget(button2);
 parentWidget->setLayout(layout);
 setCentralWidget(parentWidget);
```

Comment: I was setting the size before I was trying to set the layouts. Like I said, I tried sizeHint(), but that wasn't working and the buttons were being shown one on top of the other and huge.
Also, what is this auto thing? (I'm researching, but I'm already asking, since you suggested)
Thanks for the help, Victor. =)

Comment: I used `auto` to avoid writing the type name twice. It's syntactic sugar from C++11 standard. Setting the size is always useless if you use layouts because they change the geometry of the objects inside itself. `sizeHint` would not work there as I have told already, nothing will work without central widget.

Comment: Got it! I'll try making the Central Widget then and then report back. There was no Central Widget in the examples. Although Qt always create that, I was avoiding doing it so I could follow the examples as closely as possible.
Now, another doubt. Since no resizing would work, what should I do if I wanted a specific widget from a layout, like a button or something, to have a different size (bigger, or wider, whatever)?

Comment: Then, when you have a central widget and a layout inside it, you may set its size hint to one you want. the `sizeHint` would not work as same as `setGeometry` without central widget because nothing would work without central widget - I meant that.

Comment: Didn't work. setCentralWidget doesn't accept a layout (that I know from documentation). I put one of the buttons, since the program is just two buttons. One of the buttons kept the size of the main window, while the other saw no effect of the setLayout.
Probably doing something wrong, but from the examples I see, there's no need to instantiate a "QWidget *centralWidget", but Qt does that when creating a project with the .ui file.
I'm looking for other examples.

Comment: Did not understand. You should create a `QWidget` manually, set it to be `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`, then set a layout to **this** central widget, and so on, just as in my example. To change `sizeHint` from outside the widget you work with, you have `setMaximumSize` and `setMinimumSize` methods which set the internal size hint's data. Example is in the answer. Could you mark the answer accepted if it was helpful for you? And forget Qt manuals, most of time they are not helpful and even contain mistakes.

Comment: I did it, and it worked.
I asked about the resizing because the size of the main window was a little bigger, height-wise. Besides that, when I maximized the window, the buttons were stretched to fit all the window, but only widht-wise.
Anywho, thanks for the helpful answer!
Please, mark it as a good question (good amount of information and tests, before asking, whatever).
Also, I cannot mark it as helpful because I don't have 15 of reputation. But, I will mark it as the accepted answer, even thought you haven't answered my question. Your answer, almost more importantly, worked!

Comment: Bottom line, I was just reporting what happened.
Thanks a LOT Victor. I can now move on! =D

Comment: Thank you too, @Werneck! Though, to make buttons not to stretch, you should set both size hints to something.. Then, the another thing that matters, the layout tries to fill the parent widget, so you should set its `sizeConstraint` to the one you like. Also, if you want the layout to fill less area, you may add another widget to your central widget as a child, set a layout to it, and then do anything else. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is about a separate question :) The stackoverflow rules disallow commenting on anything not related to the original question. You may try to ask someone in chats.stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. That's why I told you about the direct message. I'll try to do it myself. If I can't, I'll make another question after some time researching. Not a priority now.
Thanks for the help and the honesty! =D

Answer (score 0):

After some observation, I believe I know why it wasn't working.
In the examples provided, the person was using QDialog or applying the layouts straight to the main() code, while I was using the QMainWindow class.
I suppose that when you use a QMainWindow class, you always have to set a Central Widget in order to make layouts work (setting this central widget layout).
So a solution would be:

```
QWidget centerWidget = new QWidget();
setCentralWidget(centerWidget);
//Add buttons, lists, and whatever

/*Add a QHBoxLayout or a QVBoxLayout and use
layout->addWidget() to add the widgets created,
like the examples. Then:*/

centerWidget->setLayout(layout);
```

It works, like Victor Polevoy suggested. Just answering as I believe I understood why weren't my QLayouts working.